# SQL to find last sibling in a linked list

Tags: sqlite

I've got a simple table that has a `previous` field for each row so as to create a linked list.  I am trying to find a query that will find the id of the last element in the list.  My first thought was that perhaps I could use some sort of self join, but I'm not sure how to express that what I am looking for is the id of the element which does not appear as the "previous" field in some other row.

My second thought was perhaps a query that uses "not in" and the list of all ids (e.g. `SELECT id`) but I'm not sure how to attach that a particular field (e.g. `previous`).  In other words, I would want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (SELECT id) NOT IN previous
```

But the SQL code is expecting `previous` to be a table, whereas I want to find where non of the ids are in the `previous` value.

If I try the reverse, for some reason it matches all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE previous NOT IN (SELECT id)
```

Comment: As for the second thought: `SELECT id FROM foo f1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT previous FROM foo f2)` …?

Comment: (Maybe with added `WHERE previous IS NOT NULL` for the subquery.)

Comment: @CBroe If you write that up as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the second thought:

```
SELECT id FROM foo f1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT previous FROM foo f2)
```